# Attribute with pairs of values

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom-attributes

I'm creating a store where each product has one or more "contributors" and each contributor has a contributor type (composer, arranger, artist, author, or editor). So, for instance, there may be an item with three contributors: John Doe, composer; Bob Smith, arranger; Jane Adams, arranger. I can't figure out a good way to store this information using the standard attribute types. Can anyone suggest a solution or, at least, point me in a potential right direction?

Comment: Can you please specify requirement in some more details.

Comment: I name to store a person's name as a string and I need to store a corresponding type for that person. Each product will have one or more of these people. I could just create a bunch of text attributes called `contributor1`, `contributor2`, etc. and a bunch of multiselect attributes that are `contributor1_type`, `contributor2_type`, etc. But I was hoping to store all this information in a single attribute.

Answer (score 0):

On magento 2 there is the manufacturer attribute which however is a single string.
What you need should be a multiselect with attached source model so as to select one or more matches. Here the link
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-multiselect.html

Cheers